# How to set lxcpath in config files?

Tags: config, lxc

I have put `lxc.lxcpath=/my/path` into `/etc/lxc/lxc.conf` and `/usr/local/etc/lxc/default.conf` but when I run `lxc-config lxc.lxcpath` it still shows a different path. How can I set the lxcpath? This is with lxc2.1.1 installed from sources.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running

```
lxc-config lxc.lxcpath
```

as non-root, then you need to edit ~/.config/lxc/lxc.conf instead of /etc/lxc/lxc.conf.  As in:

```
serge@sl:~$ echo "lxc.lxcpath = /tmp/xxx" > ~/.config/lxc/lxc.conf
serge@sl:~$ lxc-config lxc.lxcpath
/tmp/xxx
```

Alternatively, since you said you installed from source, it is possible that you need to edit /usr/local/etc/lxc/lxc.conf instead.  You can find the path in config.log, i.e.:

```
LXC_GLOBAL_CONF='/usr/local/etc/lxc/lxc.conf'
```